# Cant get the substr to recognise the \ character

Tags: php

Some of my users log into the system using the domain name, so if the domain is "theHub", the type in thehub\j51289 as their username.

The username ends in a session variable called username, however I need to remove the domain name from the username if it exists.

I've found substr function to work up until the \ character - and then it fails. I know that it is an escape character, but can't figure out how to implement it in my code, can anyone help?

```
    if(substr(strtoupper($_SESSION['username']), 0, 7 ) === "THEHUB\") 
       { echo "it has found it"; 
         $_SESSION['username'] = str_replace(strtoupper("THEHUB\"", "", $_SESSION['username']));    
       } 
    else 
       { echo "no it has not found it";}
```

Comment: as `\` is a control character you have to escape it. Try to use: \\ instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash with another backslash.  For example:

```
echo "foo\\bar";
```

Will display the following:

```
foo\bar
```

In this case it sounds like you want to use `"THEHUB\\"`.

Answer (score 0):

Use addslashs to escape the string. https://www.php.net/addslashes

Answer (score 0):

`\` Will escape the `"` `\\` will escape the `\`

Answer (score 0):

You should escape backslash `\` with another backslash : `\\`  like this : `"THEHUB\\"`

(You can have a look here : http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)